# Notification Settings on Xiaomi Devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, xiaomi

I'm currently working on a chat client for Android. When I've created the channel notification (only one for all the notification, am I doing something wrong?) I've set the priority to HIGH, and the notifications works like a charm. On Xiaomi Devices, settings for notifications of specific application are pretty different from the standard one. Settings for notification of a single application are:

1. Show notification
2. Floating notification
3. Lock screen notification
4. Sound
5. Vibration
6. Notification light

So, when I create my channel following Android guidance, my notification channel is created with only 1 and 5 active, and the result is that notification is not useful on Xiaomi devices if user doesn't setup them correctly from device settings. I can accept this behaviour if it will be standard, but I've tried to install Telegram to Xiaomi device and all these settings are enabled by default.
My question is: How they achieve that? How can I enable by default all these settings when I create my channel for notifications?

Comment: any update about it ?

Comment: unfortunately, nothing.

Comment: I have some problem about this , setting notification in Xiaomi default is disabled, it must manually enable by user.

Comment: @AlessioCrestani Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: there isn't. The only solution is to contact Xiaomi to Whitelist your application.

Comment: @AlessioCrestani any idea on how can we do that?

Comment: @FredericoSilva Nope, actually you cannot achieve this. We have done a modal when vendor is Xiaomi that guide user on settings to enable notifications. Unfortunately if you aren't a big app provider, they don't help you.